# conditional function arguments in typescript

Tags: typescript, function-parameter, conditional-types

Is it possible to have a conidial required argument type based on the first argument type:

```
type ConditionalRequiredArg<T, P> = T extends string ? P | undefined : P;

function func<T, P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2: ConditionalRequiredArg<T, P>) {}

func('foo'); // Error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

In theory, the above function should not require a second argument, but it does!

Edit: I am aware of '?' for optional argument types, but I would like to make it conditional to leverage the compiler error and suggestions.

Comment: Why do you define an optional type and expect an optional argument behaviour from the function? You can make the argument optional by putting a ? at the end of the argument as follows: function func<T, P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2?: ConditionalRequiredArg<T, P>)

Comment: it's more of curiosity and trying possibilities. i know i can use the '?' to make it optional, but i would like it to be conditional so the user knows when a second argument is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the [signature overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to screen users from directly using the implementation signature:

```
function func<P>(_arg1: string, _arg2?: P)
function func<P>(_arg1: number, _arg2: P)
function func<P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2?: P) { }
```

This code forces user to choose either the first signature or the second to use, and not the third signature of the implementation.

```
func('foo', 1); // success
func('foo'); // success
func(1, 1); // success
func(1); // Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution to making the second argument of the function defined would be to
mark it optional using the `?` operator and have the following:

```
// ...
function func<T, P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2?: ConditionalRequiredArg<T, P>) {}
// ...
```

However, if you want to make more changes take a look at the following:

```
/*
 * You could remove the conditional type to get a better inference on the generics
 * that are used and simply check the typeof _arg1 and if it is string as you had
 * defined in the ConfitionalRequiredArg it will use a type in the generic arg
 * you would then have to provide
 */
function func<P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2?: typeof _arg1 extends string ? P | undefined : P) {}

func<string>('foo', 4); // ts error 4 is not assignable to type string | undefined
```

Essentially in the end, to make an argument optional, use the `?` operator.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQASVgHgAoD4AUA+gIYBOA5gIwBcqAznKQlOagD6pQQC2ARgKakANKhIUATAH5acAJ4AHfkjCiyVVPwAecflAAmdeo2atJqbO1TQ9-MM357UtbAEpUAbwC+oUBhiYGJhYCAHIwJCQQkQAWFwBuIA)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up two different things.

```
func<T, P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2: ConditionalRequiredArg<T, P>)
```

means that the function expects 2 arguments, where the second one might have the type undefined, meaning:

`_arg2 = undefined`, where the field `_arg2` is already declared.

But you want the field to be not declared.

`_arg2 = undefined` is not equivalent of saying:

```
func<T, P>(_arg1: string | number, undefined)
```

For this use case, you can use ? as follows:

```
func<T, P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2?: ConditionalRequiredArg<T, P>)
```

Edit:

Types and arguments are two different things. The type defines the type of the value, whilst an argument is a field.

Although it is not a good practice, you could also initialize the field manually with undefined as follows:

```
func<T, P>(_arg1: string | number, _arg2: string = undefined)
```

But this is in the end same as `_arg2?`

The type `undefined` is like saying "The field does not contain anything" or better say, "The field contains undefined", whilst the field `undefined` is "The field does not exist"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i am aware of '?' for optional arguments type, but i was hoping to make it conditional and leverage the compiler error and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As @daylily said, if you are able to use the signature overloading syntax, then that's definitely the way to go. However, if you need to infer generics then I would usually conditionally generate a tuple:

```
function assertPerson<
    Age extends number
>(
    ...args: 0 extends Age ? [age: Age] : [age: Age, name: string]
) {
    const [age, maybeName] = args; // [number, string | undefined]
}

assertPerson(2, "hey");
assertPerson(0)
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoAVuoIA8AUIuYgIIDmGiGAHlBmACaqJggC2ARtiQB8ACjIUAdJORZqqAFyIADPSYt2VWogD8iANrJaCmhgC6iBfsMaMAGk7JuGBaihYYYaiZIBKRAG8xcggEFz0DW0RuZABPfgA5B1NEAF4UGVQAbkQAemy9Lj5sOxc3D0QAH0RwVgxgdwxWLwBfEhI0TBx8LEIwYQAmOwAiAAsMaMHvDLb0bDwCBGFFbxIgA)

Comment: interesting solution, thanks.